# Vim: change the cursor shape in overtype mode?

Tags: vim, xterm

In my vimrc file I put the following code in order to change the cursor shape:

```
if &term =~ "xterm"
  " blinking vertical bar
  let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[5 q"
  " blinking block
  let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[1 q"
endif
```

It works great but now I'd like to take it further and change also the cursor shape (blinking underscore) whenever the overtype mode is used (r and R keys).
How could I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `t_SR` for that. For example, to get an underscore as you suggest, your configuration would look like:

```
if &term =~ "xterm"
  " blinking vertical bar
  let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[5 q"
  " blinking block
  let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[1 q"
  " blinking underscore
  let &t_SR .= "\<Esc>[3 q"
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim does not support this.  To see that, look at the `term_cursor_shape()` function in [term.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/term.c).  That provides the shape for insert/non-insert which you are already using (as extensions to termcap).

Other termcap symbols which vim uses are the conventional flavors of invisible (vi), normal (ve) and very visible (vs).  But vim uses those to handle a quirk of scrolling.

Reading further, the only place where vim appears to make the replace-status visible is in the `showmode()` function in [screen.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/vim/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/screen.c)